# Вызов функции до ее фактического объявления

Tags: c++, функции, рекурсия

Знатокам С++

Знаю, что в C++ вызов функции возможен только после её фактического объявления. Но что делать, если такая ситуация:

Есть 2 функции, одна может рекурсивно задействовать другую.

```
double Meth1()
{

    {...}        

    if (...) return Meth1();
    else return (Meth2());
}

double Meth2()
{

    {...}        

    if (...) return Meth2();
    else return (Meth1());
}
```

Компилятор ругается на вызов Meth2() в функции **Meth1**, т.к. она фактически не объявлена. Как можно явно указать такой случай?

Comment: Да, я пытался найти информацию сам. Если обратился сюда, значит не нашел! Советовать мне это не требуется!

Comment: А что за странные лишние скобки в некоторых `return`?

Comment: И правда, лишние =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Используйте [предварительное объявление](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)

```
double Meth2(); //forward declaration, прототип должен совпадать

double Meth1()
{
   return Meth2(); //уже используем
}

double Meth2()  // а теперь рассчитаемся с компилятором 
{
  ...
}
```

А вот [ссылка для классов](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class) (раздел Forward declaration)